# Browser tries to load files locally instead of loading img from remote source

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webos

I am developing an app for LG WebOS TV with Vue. WebOS device using `Chromium  53.0.2785.0` .There is an issue with binding an image src, browser trying to load files locally instead of load it from remote source.

I tried to add "http" manually, but not succeeded. I think it is some issue with this browser version.

```
<img :src="record.showpic" alt="showPreview">
```

I see, in developer tools, link like this `"file://images.peer5.net..."` but expect `"http://images.peer5.net..."`. It works as expected in last Chrome browser.

```
"vue": "2.5.21",
"@babel/polyfill": "7.2.5"
```

**record.showpic value:**

```
"record.showpic" : "//images.peer5.net/thumbs/records/2019-05-19/28-1.stream/08-00.jpg?second=1800&amp;width=384&amp;height=216"
```

Comment: What is the value of `record.showpic`?

Comment: @ma_dev_15, question updated.

Comment: Try adding `http` to `record.showpic` and pass that in the src

Comment: @ma_dev_15, no success, as I mentioned above it is not work. URL after this is:  
`file:///media/developer/apps/usr/palm/applications/com.domain.app/http//images.peer5.net/thumbs/records/2019-05-19/29-1.stream/09-00.jpg?second=150&width=384&height=216` .   
So, for some reasons browser adding path of device app directory.

Comment: Your last comment makes it look like you have `http//images...` when it should be `http://images...`

Comment: thx guys, missed ":")